# Text in XML Graphical Layout appears as strange characters

Tags: android

I am having issues viewing text in the graphical layout section of my android applications. This is consistently happening across many projects, new and old. See the link for visual example:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/wE0o2.jpg

The button in the image should say 'test' but instead its two boxes. Sometimes it appears as an open bracket, [

Background- I was having issues with eclipse/android sdk not creating the R.java file when a new project was created so I uninstalled the sdk and then reinstalled it. The R.java file builds fine now but the text in the graphic layouts is all strange characters.

Any idea what I can do to fix this?

The XML has one warning, which is 'Hardcoded string "test", should use @string resource"
I don't think this is the issue because I have had this error before on working applications.

EDIT:

XML code-

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:text="test" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Could you show your XML File ? Did you set the right encoding ?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I added it to the initial post

Comment: Try to add `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` in the first line of the XML file

Comment: I'm not sure what your problem is yet but that warning is just saying that you should put `Strings` in the `strings.xml` and reference them from there like `android:text="@string/test". There are several reasons for this, one being that it is much easier to change and reference if you use it in multiple places. One Google I/O presentation says "DON"T hard code strings"

Comment: @codeMagic yes, I'm aware of what the warning means. I just mentioned it in an attempt to provide as much info for you

Comment: @ZouZou adding that line did not make a difference, unfortunately. Shouldn't that line be auto-generated in the XML when the android project is created?

Comment: It should. What's the encodingof your project ?

Comment: Ok, I was just trying to be helpful because from this statement, "I don't think this is the issue...", it sounded like you may not have been sure

Comment: @ZouZou how do I check that? sorry, still learning eclipse

Comment: Right click on the project -> Properties -> Resources -> Text file encoding. Are you using a particular font to display this text ?

Comment: Sorry this has taken so long to reply, I have been busy with other non-android related projects. The Text File encoding option that is selected is "Inherited from container (Cp1252)"

I selected "Other" and chose UTF-8 and applied the changes, yet the characters are still appearing the same way.

Comment: @ZouZou The text view properly displays characters when I change the typeface to Serif. However, it shows the goofy characters when I have the typeface set at Normal and Sans. The text file encoding is still the same as it was in my previous reply on June 6.

Comment: @csterling If this appears only with the graphical layout, I won't pay attention to it since those polices are very common and you won't have any problem using it on emulators or real devices.

Comment: @ZouZou while it is true that I am not having issues displaying text on the device, I'm looking for a solution to this issue...it's frustrating! It would be ideal if the software was working 100%, wouldn't you agree?

Comment: @csterling Do you have set a custom device screen configuration for your graphical layout before update the ADT ?

Comment: @ZouZou No, I don't have any custom device screen configs...as far as I know. I just create a new project and the text is not encoded correctly.

Comment: @csterling Are your sure ? Could you check that ? (http://i.imgur.com/8otl2.png)

Comment: @ZouZou Here is what I see: http://i.imgur.com/SwMdtPG.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are having font issues with your emulator. It can't find appropriate characters to display.  You may need to reinstall that.

Comment: I'm not using the emulator. It's in the eclipse environment where I am experiencing these issues.

Comment: I'm confused... the picture you pointed to here  http://i.imgur.com/OwENudf.jpg  is from an emulator.

Comment: No, its from the graphical layout view in the xml file. Sorry for the confusion, I just cropped it in a confusing way

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I searched and I think it will fix your problem (and it was too long to post it as a comment).

Go to the platforms folder where android-sdk is installed (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platforms`).
Then go to the folders you're currenlty building your projects with then go to data/fonts (i.e `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-8\data\fonts`) and take a look at the file `fonts.xml`. Also, may a ttf file disappeared when you updated your ADT (which seems odd).

You can find here an [example](http://www.opendebug.com/article/443121). Read this carefully before trying to modify these files.

I hope this will solve your problem. If not, I have really no idea about what to do.

Comment: I do not have a file named fonts.xml ...the only xml files in the \data\fonts directory are: fallback_fonts.xml, fallback_fonts-ja.xml, system_fonts.xml, and vendor_fonts.xml


Should I just reinstall the SDK?

Comment: @csterling Yes try to reinstall it.